# Why does the Steam wishlist behavior of UFO 50 differ from other pre-release titles?

Tags: steam

I have several "Coming soon" titles on my Steam wishlist. I often hide them by filtering out pre-release titles but for some reason the game UFO 50 is not hidden. It also has a "View Details" button that is missing from other pre-release titles. See the screen shot below. Why does the Steam wishlist behavior of UFO 50 differ from other pre-release titles?

[image: Pre-release titles on Steam wishlist]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens with product pages that have more then one sku on them.

The difference in wording makes a bit more sense when the product is available for purchase, and you have to pick which particular sku you want to add to your cart:

[image: view details on a released product]

Comment: I thought UFO 50 would essentially be one game that contained several mini games and a menu. I guess it could still be tagged in the store as a game collection. Who knows. Perhaps the individual games will be packaged as DLC for logistical reasons.

Comment: Bundles and DLC don't trigger this behavior (e.g. *Life is Strange 2*), only multiple "entry point" products. You're right that it does suggest something interesting about how this game will be released.